# updating table by using another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Email` which have a column called `Email` which consist of all emails
and another table called `peronaldomains` which has a column called `domains` consist of all domains

I want to update a column in `Email` table called `email_type_id` which I want to update to `email_type_id = 2` for whatever email that has domains matching to `domains` column in `personaldomains` table

`eg abcd.abc.com`, `efgh.abc.com`, `ghik.abc.com` in `Email` column in `email` table has `abc.com` in `domains` columns of `personaldomains` table

the `email` table has around 6 million rows and `personaldomains` table has 1213 rows.

I am using mysql

the query i used to create `personaldomains` table is

```
create table personaldomains
SELECT RIGHT(Email, CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(Email)) - Locate('@', Email)) Domains ,
COUNT(Email) EmailCount
FROM   email
WHERE  email_type_id = 2 and
CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(Email)) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(Email, CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(Email)) - Locate('@', Email))
ORDER BY EmailCount desc
```

Comment: @timo.rieber beat me to it by 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have this expression:

```
RIGHT(Email, CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(Email)) - Locate('@', Email))
```

I think it's something like

```
UPDATE email e
SET e.email_type_id = 2
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x' 
    FROM personaldomains pd 
    WHERE pd.domain = 
      RIGHT(e.Email, CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(e.Email)) - Locate('@', e.Email)))
```

Comment: this gives an error  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: I think I forgot a closing parentheses.